# Minimum dependencies needed to build a Jersey service with Maven on Netbeans that runs on Tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, netbeans, jersey

I have recently moved from developing Jersey Web services on Eclipse to Netbeans and I am having some issues.

(1) I am not able to figure out the minimum maven dependencies needed to develop and deploy a Jersey Web service on Tomcat. Right now I have to explicitly add the org.glassfish.jersey.containers dependency within every service I create.

(2) As Netbeans does not generate a war file, I would have to use the maven-war plugin to explicitly generate a war if I need to move the app to a remote server. Is there a better way of generating the war through Netbeans itself without using the plugin?

(3)Is there an example or tutorial on developing the service from first principles on Netbeans with maven that runs on tomcat with a war generated in Tomcat webapps, rather than selecting the predefined REST Service patterns that come inbuilt with Netbeans?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Nimonika,

Let's start with question 2. You could try to right-click on the project and choose "Clean and build" from the menu. If you accidentally closed the "Projects" tab you can press Ctrl+1 or select it from the "Window" menu. Then, in the "Files" tab you can see inside your project folder the "target" folder. If you can't find the tab, press Ctrl+2 or select it from the "Window" menu. There should reside your war-file.

Going on to questions 1 and 3, it should be mentioned that such a project could be created using a maven archetype. You could either generate it using maven an then open the resulting project in NetBeans or you can generate it right in the IDE. To do the latter, please choose "New project" from the "File" menu (or press the button with a plus sign below the menu or press Ctrl+Shift+N).

[image: New project from archetype]

In the dialog which shows, please select "Maven" in "Categories" list and then in the list called Projects scroll down and select "Project from Archetype". Then in a new dialog in the input field called "Search" type in the word "jersey" (without quotes). You'll see a lot of archetypes the descriptions of which appear when you click on them. Probably jersey-quickstart-webapp could suit your needs.

[image: Select Archetype]

Finally, there is a nice [Jersey tutorial](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-webapp) on their site and it describes a project that you got using the aforementioned way. Also there is a description how to create the project from the command line using maven.

To see what Maven goals are executed when you right-click the project and select an option from the menu you can, yes, right-click the project and select "Properties". In "Categories"  list select "Actions" and after that click on various actions and read the description.

[image]

Good Luck.